# Using SimpleXML to get "Form" element which have "input" tag with type "password"?

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath, simplexml

Hi 
  I have webpage data (html converted into xml) consisting of many forms , I want to grab the form which have input tag inside it of type password ( not necessary direct children) . consider example below data stored inside variable $html

```
<html>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" name="foo" />
</form>

<form>
<table>
<tr> <input type="password" name="pass"/> </tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried

```
$loginForm  =  $html->xpath('//form//input[@type="password"]//../form');
```

But didnt succeeded :(

Thanks.

Comment: what are you getting for '//form//input[@type="password"]'

Comment: //form , //input for ancestor descendent's relation ship ,targeting type attribute with value password . Problem is after I get the input element of type password I am unable to go back to the nearest form ancestor .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this XPath:

```
//form[descendant::input[@type="password"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
//form//input[@type="password"]/ancestor::form
```